Need an advice to rig a spaceship with mechanicals part
I'm trying to rig a spaceship and I'm getting stuck on a specific problem. Here is a simplified blend to illustrate the problem.

I'm looking for a way to rig these different elements so that when you turn the handwheel, it bends the bending bow (I don't care if the pulley is animated or not).
Do you have any ideas ?
Here are some images of the spaceship I'm working on:




Initial setup
First let's make a simple bone setup: a root bone, parent of a wheel bone, parent of a crank bone.

Note how I oriented the bones with +Z upwards and +Y on whatever their main rotation axe they represent.
With this, you have the basics functionalities for your "whole objects" to move together, and your wheel to rotate. The Crank bone will be useful as a target to "hook" the rope's curve start point onto.
In pose mode, select the wheel bone, set its Rotation Mode to XYZ Euler, then write #frame/10 in its Y rotation input to make it driven by the current frame value divided by 10. Which will make it spin indefinitely during playback, a handy test for our case.
Hooking the crank
In Pose Mode, select the Crank bone. Then in object mode, ⇧ Shift select the curve object, ↹ Tab into edit mode, box-select the curve points at
Hit ⎈ CtrlH to open the Hooks menu, select Hook To Selected Object Bone:

Doing this will create a Hook modifier on the curve object, which as its name suggests, "hooks" the selected part of the curve object to the Crank bone.

Since your rope model "starts" where that curve point happens, the movement of the Crank bone affecting that point makes the whole rope mesh "slide" on the curve:

Rigging the rope tip
Let's add a new bone in our armature with its head at the tip of the rope, but with its tail at the middle point of the curve. That way we have a bone that "starts" at the tip and is perfectly aligned with that portion of the curve.
Let's do the same hooking procedure as the above, but with the BendingBow curve this time. Select the Tip bone, then the tip curve point of the bow, ⎈ CtrlH and hook to selected bone.
That way the bow deforms with the Tip bone, but now we need to make that bone move with the crank, and along the rope curve.
For that, back in pose mode in the armature, select the Crank Bone and ⇧ Shift select the Tip bone. Press ⎈ Ctrl⇧ ShiftC to open the Add Constraint with Target menu, and chose Child Of to dynamically parent the Tip bone to the Crank, leave only its Location channels affected. Finally, add a Limit Rotation bone constraint, enable all but Y axes, and set it to Local Space. This way it can only use its local Y axis to move alongside the Crank bone.

The result is this system:

It can be polished to look better. For example the rope's curve points don't reach perfectly the crank or the bow, and its mesh is set to a finite lenght iteration whereas it could be set to fit the curve and you could hook the tip of the rope curve to the tip bone too, to always have a perfectly matching rope mesh.
